# listview not refreshing properly after using the NEXT button

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have a listview with a dropdown list choice.  The first time I come in the listview and I used NEXT button on the bottom of the listview, it display everything just fine.   If I changed the dropdown to another choice it display the list fine the first time but If I used the NEXT button it WON't refresh the listview.  I am using AJAX with an UpdatePanel. I see the listview been populated correctly (apt.Count() is returning 20 records).   Any idea of what can be wrong ?

I think I need a refresh or something like this maybe due to the AJAX ?

Here is the code behing

```
private void ListApt(int iIndexDdl)
{
    using (AptDataContext db = new AptDataContext())
    {
        var apt = from Apt in db.Apt
                  join Doctor in db.Doctor on Apt.DoctorId equals Doctor.Id

                       where Apt.doctorId == iIndexDdl && Apt.IsAvailable == true &&
                             Apt.dateApt >= DateTime.Now 
                       select Apt
                       ;

                  ListView1.DataSourceID = null;
                  ListView1.DataSource = apt;

                  int numberOfRecords = apt.Count();
                  if (numberOfRecords == 0)
                  {
                      lblMessage.Text = "No Appointement are available";
                  }

                  ListView1.DataBind();
    };
}
```

Here is where the button are define in the .aspx

```
   <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" >
      <Fields>
          <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" 
            ShowLastPageButton="True" />
      </Fields>
  </asp:DataPager>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListViewPersons" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="ProductItem">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelEmail" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LabelName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ProductItem"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
                    <hr />
                </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListViewPersons" 
                onprerender="DataPager1_PreRender">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListViewPersons" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindListView();                
        }
    }

    private void BindListView()
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Person aPerson =new Person();
            aPerson.Email = "Email" + i.ToString();
            aPerson.Name = "Name" + i.ToString();
            persons.Add(aPerson);
        }

        ListViewPersons.DataSource = persons;
        ListViewPersons.DataBind();
    }        

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

    protected void DataPager1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindListView();
    }
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/513399/UpdateplusPanelplusdataplusisplusnotplusrefreshing

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Comment: @Kaplan where I am adding this in the <asp:DataPager ?

Comment: I added this <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" Autopostback="true">  but sometimes after clicking on the button nothing is refreshing?  Any idea?  nothing to do with the AJAX?

Comment: The NextPreviousPagerField is generating the NEXT button, any idea on how to include your code there?

Comment: got this error now A control with ID 'DataPager1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'  I added the Triggers after the ContentTemplate ending

Comment: The below link will help you.

Comment: thanks for the link it works better now.  Let says I have two pages of items. If I select DoctorA, I do NEXT the page2 is showing up.  If I changed for DoctorB, why it won't go to page1 but page2 of DoctorB ?   I will think it will always refresh to the first page after I change the Doctor name ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you sure there are more records to retrieve?  Perhaps you are at the end of the list.

2) Use debug mode on your browser.  There could be an error being thrown that will hose your AJAX after the first refresh from the drop down.

3) Pay attention to what controls are inside the update panel, and what controls are triggers for updating.

You should defiantly post your markup code as well.  The problem is most likely in your markup or the wiring of controls and events.